# How to embed two different Angular 2 applications inside another Angular 2 application without using IFrame

Tags: angular, user-interface

I have two different Angular 2 applications ( say app1 and app2 ) deployed on two different servers ( server1 and server2 ) and i want to use or embed those applications inside a third Angular 2 application ( app3 ) which will be deployed on a different server ( server3 ).
Is it possible to solve the above problem without using IFrame in app3.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it really is solvable. The angular2 framework supports making modules to contain features. So you can name your application modules as per your actual app name rather than 'app'. Then you can include those modules of your app1 and app2 inside app3.

Now all this means that you have the actual code base rather than the url address for the application.

This is a very basic use case that Angular2 solves very well. You can find code for this very easily. You just have to mention imports array while defining your app3 module. This import array will contain names of app1 and app2.

Hope this answer guides you well to make your application.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But it would be helpful if you will share some sample code or link  for that as i am new to Angular 2. Also please explain little bit  further as all the application have different code base and also deployed on three different servers. So on app3 i how will i access the other two angular 2 applications. How will i access the module of one angular 2 application into the other angular 2 application which is having different code base as well as deployed on different server.