# Embedding Angular 4 SPA inside another jQuery based application

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc-4

I looked at some other threads, like:

[How to embed two different Angular 2 applications inside another Angular 2 application without using IFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42401138/how-to-embed-two-different-angular-2-applications-inside-another-angular-2-appli)

[How to embed a self-contained Angular 2 application inside of an Angular 1 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34802717/how-to-embed-a-self-contained-angular-2-application-inside-of-an-angular-1-appli)

But, I have a different use case, where I would like to embed Angular 2 application inside another application, using jQuery in the front end and I don't want to use iFrames for embedding the Angular applications.

**About Application:**

I have an existing .Net MVC based application using jQuery in the frontend. Front end of the application is a tab based application, and has it's own Frontend routing. Something like:

> https:///appM#!b/stats/?
>
> https:///appM#!m/users/?

and so on. When user click any of the tab or links in the application, the content (HTML+data) of that particular screen is dynamically loaded, view is updated with the content received and that tab is marked active.

**Angular 2/4:**

Now, I have couple of small Angular 2/4 applications that I want to embed to each one of these tabs. These Angular 4 apps have there own routing. something like:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: DefaultHomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'list', component: UserListComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

And, this is how I have composed my module with it route:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, UserListModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: false })],
    declarations: [AppComponent, DefaultHomeComponent, AppRootComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppRootComponent],
    providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/appM#!b/stats/?' }, ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I am able to Bootstrap the Angular app in a given tab, and it works fine, until, I click any link outside of the angular app. Whenever, I click such a link, I get long JS error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'appM'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'appM'
    at ApplyRedirects.webpackJsonp.../../../router/@angular/router.es5.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (eval at globalEval (jquery.js:328), <anonymous>:81982:16)
    at CatchSubscriber.eval [as selector] (eval at globalEval (jquery.js:328), <anonymous>:81957:29)
    at CatchSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/catch.js.CatchSubscriber.error (eval at globalEval (jquery.js:328), <anonymous>:8378:31)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (eval at globalEval (jquery.js:328), <anonymous>:1448:26)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (eval at globalEval (jquery.js:328), <anonymous>:1422:18)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (eval at globalEval (jquery.js:328), <anonymous>:1448:26)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (eval at globalEval (jquery.js:328), <anonymous>:1422:18)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (eval at globalEval (jquery.js:328), <anonymous>:1448:26)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (eval at globalEval (jquery.js:328), <anonymous>:1422:18)
    at LastSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (eval at globalEval (jquery.js:328), <anonymous>:1448:26)
    at ApplyRedirects.webpackJsonp.../../../router/@angular/router.es5.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (eval at globalEval (jquery.js:328), <anonymous>:81982:16)
    at CatchSubscriber.eval [as selector] (eval at globalEval (jquery.js:328), <anonymous>:81957:29)
    at CatchSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/catch.js.CatchSubscriber.error (eval at globalEval (jquery.js:328), <anonymous>:8378:31)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (eval at globalEval (jquery.js:328), <anonymous>:1448:26)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (eval at globalEval (jquery.js:328), <anonymous>:1422:18)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (eval at globalEval (jquery.js:328), <anonymous>:1448:26)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (eval at globalEval (jquery.js:328), <anonymous>:1422:18)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (eval at globalEval (jquery.js:328), <anonymous>:1448:26)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (eval at globalEval (jquery.js:328), <anonymous>:1422:18)
    at LastSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (eval at globalEval (jquery.js:328), <anonymous>:1448:26)
    at resolvePromise (eval at globalEval (jquery.js:328), <anonymous>:8885:31)
    at resolvePromise (eval at globalEval (jquery.js:328), <anonymous>:8856:17)
    at eval (eval at globalEval (jquery.js:328), <anonymous>:8933:17)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (eval at globalEval (jquery.js:328), <anonymous>:8526:31)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (eval at globalEval (jquery.js:328), <anonymous>:56494:33)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (eval at globalEval (jquery.js:328), <anonymous>:8525:36)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (eval at globalEval (jquery.js:328), <anonymous>:8293:47)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (eval at globalEval (jquery.js:328), <anonymous>:8697:35)
    at webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask (eval at globalEval (jquery.js:328), <anonymous>:8604:21)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (eval at globalEval (jquery.js:328), <anonymous>:8589:48)
```

This is a problem only when my Angular app has it's own routing. In those cases, Angular routing is in conflicts with Site routes.

It is possible to use Angular 2/4 applications this way and configure Angular 2 routing in such a way that if a rout does not falls into it jurisdiction, it ignores the route change event, instead throwing error?

Comment: you can't user a router without declaring its endpoints

Comment: @RomanC - What exactly you mean when without declaring router end point? Am I missing any required config value for my Angular route config? but, it seems to be loading fine when I switch between Angular 2 route.

Comment: I am able to resolve the problem, I will post in my answer in a day or two

Comment: @Ravish, m wondering how you resolved the problem. I have a similar need. Care to post some answers? thanks

Comment: @SamDevx - sure, give me 2 days, I will post a detailed response.